# Help with hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

So I've got a custom module that builds a page (/simple-ajax-form) and has a form on it with the ID "payment_form" and other fields with IDs like "number_1". My module name is "Drupalup Simple Custom Form" for reference.

The problem I can't figure out (as I'm new to hook_form_alter) is that on the form ID instead of it being "payment_form" the ID gets rendered as "payment-form" and then on the input fields instead of it being "number_1" the ID get rendered as "edit-number-1".

What code do I need to make the form render as "payment_form" and inputs without "edit" and to also have underscores? And where does this code go - in my custom module?

Comment: You generally shouldn't mess with the IDs. The AJAX system needs them to remain as-is, so it's not a good idea in Drupal. You're better off finding the Drupal way to achieve whatever your goal is.

Comment: Typically HTML IDs and classes will use hyphens rather than underscores. It is common throughout Drupal's FAPI and theming systems to use underscores within the server-side code and hyphens in the rendered product. In your form definition, use sensible keys to identify the elements of your form array: e.g. `["number_1"] => ["#type" => "number", ...]`. Rely on those keys in your `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: This is the code I have that's not working. 

function Drupalup_Simple_Custom_Form_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {                                           
    if($form_id == 'payment-form'){
    $form['#form_id'] = 'payment_form';
    }
    }

From the reading I've done a hook_form_alter IS the Drupal way. I just can't get it to work

Comment: the hook definition should be lowercases, like `drupalup_simple_custom_form_form_alter` otherwise drupal will not recognise your function as hook.

Comment: Still not working having amended to lowercase :(

Comment: Figured it out - put it the ID request in to an array:

$form['#attributes'] = array('id' => array('payment_form'));

Instead of 

public function getFormId() {
    return 'payment_form';
  }

Comment: What is the difference? I have never had an issue with this - converting underscores to dashes is just how those are treated, just like field names having 'edit' prepended. The AJAX layer for forms will handle element IDs and should not be relied on in external code (Javascript files) because they will change and refresh on each interaction. FormBase implements FormInterface so getFormId() method is required by contract, so it needs to be there.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out - put it the ID request in to an array:

`$form['#attributes'] = array('id' => array('payment_form'));`

Instead of

`public function getFormId() { return 'payment_form'; }`

Comment: I don't recommend this, as it can and often does lead to unintended #ajax consequences.

Comment: If you are going to manually assign an ID, I recommend using Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getUniqueId() to ensure uniqueness and conformity to best practices. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetUniqueId/8.8.x